# How can I set my pop to download all mails from last 30 days

Tags: c#, email, gmail, pop3

I have a C# application using **pop** this is already working perfectly fine. However, I would like to program it to download all mails sent to me in the **last 30 days only** and download them even if they have been **downloaded before**.

Is there a way to set the date when to download from and how can I set pop to download all mails even if they have been downloaded before? I don't want to set this in my Gmail but rather in **code**.

Comment: Here is a question of mine that can show u my code. http://stackoverflow.com/q/10528954/1356321 . This is a similar question also Unanswered.

Comment: Did you check this? http://james.apache.org/server/rfclist/pop3/rfc1725.txt

Comment: This is a lot to read could you tel me what you want me to read in this document ?

Comment: Supposed to mark up for good really hard question!, not mark down because you did not know the answer :\ sigh the people who would know are not going to check it out now ...

Comment: You're writing a POP3 client, I think the answer to your question is not specific to Gmail. How the feature you want to implement works might be explained in the RFC. And actually, the link I first gave you is outdated, this one seems more up to date: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1939.txt And you should read it whole.

Comment: Thanks so is there a way to set pop3 properties though code?

Comment: There perfect Answer!!!!!!

If you add recent: before your username. E.g Me@gmail.com = recent:Me@gmail.com

Recent mode fetches the last 30 days of mail, regardless of whether it's been sent to another POP1 client already.

Can read it right here.

http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47948

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There perfect Answer!!!!!!

If you add recent: before your username. E.g Me@gmail.com = recent:Me@gmail.com

Recent mode fetches the last 30 days of mail, regardless of whether it's been sent to another POP1 client already.

Can read it right here.

http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47948

Answer (score 1):

Just continue downloading messages from the pop server while the

```
msg.Headers.DateSent;
```

is within the

```
DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30);
```

Comment: Its not the Solution to my main problem, but at least it shortens my mail list making testing faster. could you read my last edit, on the last line in my question, that's my main problem

Comment: There perfect Answer!!!!!!

If you add recent: before your username. E.g Me@gmail.com = recent:Me@gmail.com

Recent mode fetches the last 30 days of mail, regardless of whether it's been sent to another POP1 client already.

Can read it right here.

http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47948