# Enable Gmail POP3 settings using API

Tags: c#, .net, api, gmail

I want to access Gmail messages through POP3. The problem is that I need to ask the user to always go to his/her account settings and select: `"Enable POP for all mail (even mail that's already been downloaded)"` I was wondering if Gmail has provided an API for this setting. I'm writing my app in C#.

Comment: Perhaps this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528954/how-can-re-enable-pop-in-gmail-from-c-sharp-code

Comment: @Bridge Although the question really seems like it's a duplicate, the solution provided for it won't work for me. I want to change the setting without asking the user for doing it. This is different than what the OP of that question wants.

Comment: I know - that's why had I changed my comment from originally saying "potential duplicate" to "perhaps this might help" :-)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately still having the same problem. Hopefully I can find an API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently using this API: [ActiveUp](http://mailsystem.codeplex.com/) For all my POP3 and IMAP4 needs. I recomend you take a look at it and if you need any help just shoot me a message! Hope this helped!

Comment: I use it all the time, Like I said, if you need help let me know!

Comment: Just, please tell me, where is the documentation? Does it contain some samples? I'm downloading the code now.

Comment: BTW, does it have a NUGET package?

Comment: I'm not sure about the NUGET question but as far as the documentation I have yet to find any but if you need help feel free to email me: team.m44m31@gmail.com or skype me: m44m31

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20851/discussion-between-m44m31-and-alireza-noori)